# PiTiVi crashes with segmentation fault on importing .mp4 files

Tags: video, pitivi

My video camera records onto a memory card which mounts in Ubuntu with no problem.  I see a bunch of .mp4 files, but what software do I use now?  I installed PiTiVi and repeatedly tried to import the folder of .mp4 files but it keeps crashing after importing a few of them.  I tried running `pitivi` from the command line to see if it output any messages, but all I saw were errors about creating thumbnails and then "Segmentation fault".  Now what?

Answer (score 2):

That does sound like a bug in PiTiVi.  You could try other video editing software like [Avidemux](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avidemux) or try to convert the video to a format more likely to work with [OggConvert](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/oggconvert).  Both are supposed to be able to handle mp4 files.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get Avidemux to work with a whole list of files ("for they are many" :)  Haven't tried OggConvert yet...